# Error in finding column sum of 2 dim array in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
void sum_col(int *ar, int rows)
{
    int c, r, total;
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    {
        total = 0;
        for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            total += ar[r][c];  // error occurs
        printf("%dth column sum: %d", c + 1, total);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to define a function which prints column sums of a 2 dimensional array. But error occurs in `total += ar[r][c]`. What's wrong with this sentence?

Comment: The first problem is that `ar` is a pointer to `int` i.e. a single-dimensional array, something that should be very clear from your error messages. You need it to be a pointer to arrays of `int`, or a pointer to pointer to `int` (depending on what the argument actually is). Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `int **ar` in the first line?

Comment: @Wickramaranga Not if the actual variable being passed is an array of arrays.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Okay. I will keep that in mind!